# Is it possible to filter traffic based on client reverse dns?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

As the question states, I would like to filter out all traffic for users based on a pattern of reverse dns hostname.

For example (and only as an example -- this is not my exact usecase), I would like to be able to add a pattern of `google-public-dns-[a-z]\.google\.com` that would match traffic coming from 8.8.8.8 (given that `8.8.8.8.in-addr.arpa name = google-public-dns-a.google.com.`).

Comment: Should this filter ALL traffic, or are you trying to filter traffic for specific services?

Comment: In this case you might find these urls useful:
https://campus.barracuda.com/product/emailsecuritygateway/doc/39819732/reverse-dns-blocking/
and
https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/rdns/

Comment: I believe it's possible to append custom parameters to Google Analytics, and then filter based on those parameters (for instance, if users log in to your app then you could filter your analytics by user group). If your server performed the reverse DNS lookup either as part of loading the page or as an asynchronous API call and returned this value prior to the Google Analytics code running then you could append the resulting hostname as a custom variable.

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/google-analytics-custom-variables/

Comment: I'm hoping that GA will handle this somehow. I know there are filters for "ISP Domain" but that appears to do some other kind of traffic source identification that isn't reverse DNS.

Comment: GA is quite restrictive over access to IP address data and their terms limit identifiable data in their custom variables.  Rather than filtering out the users at GA, have you considered carrying out the lookup on your own server and only including the analytics code for non-matching requests ?

Comment: I'm actually not the owner of the GA account. I'm the owner of the bots that are generating the traffic to GA. I'm looking to advise my customers (who control the site the bots are hitting) how to filter out my traffic.